# VBA: WithEvents puzzle

Tags: events, vba, excel, userform

I have a UserForm, **xForm**, that is being instantiated in a class module (let's say **TestClass**) as:

```
'TestClass
Dim Form as New xForm
Private WithEvents EvForm as MSForms.UserForm
Set EvForm = Form
```

At the class module of the xForm itself I have some code that must be executed on Form Closing, ONLY if the form actually closes:

```
'xForm class module
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    'Do some cleanup, otherwise the app would hang
    'If not closing, don't cleanup anything, otherwise the app would hang
End Sub
```

The QueryClose event is also treated in TestClass, and could avoid the form from closing:

```
'TestClass
Private Sub EvForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    'Verify if closing is allowed based on User Control values
    Cancel = Not ClosingIsAllowed '<-- Pseudocode on the right side of "="
End Sub
```

How can I test for Cancel = True, set in TestClass, in the xForm class module?
Let's rephrase it: If Cancel is set to True in TestClass, I must not do the cleanup code in the xForm class module. How can I accomplish that?

Until now, I have thought off of implementing another event in the xForm class (My_QueryClose?) and raise it on the QueryClose event. Outside the Code Behind Form I would deal only with the My_QueryClose event, so taking full control over what is happening. Is this a viable/better approach?

Comment: Did you compile (Debug menu -> Compile) the code? I am unable to use `withevents` with the line such as `Private WithEvents EvForm as xForm` inside the `TestClass`?

Comment: Sorry, shahkalpesh! Indeed, it must be "... as MSForms.UserForm". Editing the question to reflect that.

Comment: Well, discovered that I could use `Private WithEvents EvForm as xForm` as long as I define some Event raising in the xForm CBF. Example: `Public Event Closing()`. Forgot checking it.

Comment: I was thinking: is there an order of code execution for events? Events raised by a UserForm would be first treated in CBF and after that by any other referencing class module? Or is it the other way around? Is there a definition I can rely on or is it something definitely asynchronous?

Comment: Maybe I'm looking to the problem in a wrong way. Somehow it should be possible to avoid the application to hang doing some sharp error handling. Something to think about. This way, I may go ahead without worrying about event treatment sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A work around declaring another event**

The code bellow do what I was expecting, although it is not as neat as I wish it could be.

In the **UserForm1** code:

```
'***** UserForm1
Public Event MyQueryClose(ByRef Cancel As Integer, ByRef CloseMode As Integer, ByRef Status As String)

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
   Dim Status As String
   Cancel = True
   Status = "QueryClose"
   Debug.Print "Entered QueryClose"
   Debug.Print "Cancel = " & Cancel
   Debug.Print "Status = " & Status
   Debug.Print "Just before raising MyQueryClose"
   RaiseEvent MyQueryClose(Cancel, CloseMode, Status)
   Debug.Print "Just got back from MyQueryClose"
   Debug.Print "Cancel = " & Cancel
   Debug.Print "Status = " & Status
End Sub
```

In the **Class1** code:

```
'***** Class1
Dim UserForm As New UserForm1
Private WithEvents UF As UserForm1

Sub DoIt()
   Set UF = UserForm
   UserForm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UF_MyQueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer, Status As String)
   Debug.Print "Just entered MyQueryClose"
   Cancel = False
   Status = "MY QueryClose"
End Sub
```

In a **basic module**, to test the Class:

```
'***** Basic module
Sub TestClass()
   Dim C As New Class1
   C.DoIt
End Sub
```

And here's the end result (debug window):

```
TestClass
Entered QueryClose
Cancel = -1
Status = QueryClose
Just before raising MyQueryClose
Just entered MyQueryClose
Just got back from MyQueryClose
Cancel = 0
Status = MY QueryClose
```

Comment: I will let the question open for a few days. So, if you know of a better way of doing it, don't hesitate to answer it.

Comment: I marked this as the answer. But, again, if you happen to know a more elegant way to do it, please give a shot.

Comment: +1 I think this is the way to go.  I don't think you need the `Dim UserForm As New UserForm1` declaration though, just the `WithEvents` declaration following it.  Also, it's better to declare and instantiate your class in two steps: Dim C as Class1 at top (without "New") and in the code Set C = New Class1.  Also, if you're doing this with a modeless form, you'll want to declare it at the top of the module, so it persists after the module in which it was instantiated - "Sub TestClass" here - closes.  I think :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't make heads or tails of your custom event idea, but the way to get one class to talk to another (form or anything else, doesn't matter) is to link them up; here's a clean example:

Basic TestClass holds form object (no events needed here, let the form handle that)

```
'TestClass code
Private MyForm          As UserForm
Private mbleCanClose    As Boolean

Public Property Get CanClose() As Boolean
    CanClose = mbleCanClose
End Property
Public Property Let CanClose(pbleCanClose As Boolean)
    mbleCanClose = pbleCanClose
End Property

Public Property Get MyFormProp() As UserForm1
    Set MyFormProp = MyForm
End Property
```

Add a custom object and property to the form itself

```
'UserForm1 code
Private mParent As TestClass

Public Property Get Parent() As TestClass
    Set Parent = mParent
End Property
Public Property Set Parent(pParent As TestClass)
    Set mParent = pParent
End Property
```

Invoking the form on TestClass creation looks like this:

```
'TestClass code
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set MyForm = New UserForm1
    Load MyForm
    Set MyForm.Parent = Me
End Sub
```

And then when it's time to close the form, you check whether you can:

```
'UserForm1 code
Public Function WillMyParentLetMeClose() As Boolean
    If Not (mParent Is Nothing) Then
        WillMyParentLetMeClose = mParent.CanClose
    End If
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If WillMyParentLetMeClose = True Then
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's what it would like to invoke

```
'standard module code
Public Sub Test_TestClass()
    Dim myclass As TestClass
    Set myclass = New TestClass
    myclass.MyFormProp.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, downwitch! You've got it right. Your code should do what I was asking for. But it seems, to me, like an overkill. You're setting up a CallBack method and I think that's exactly what events are made for. Check out my own answer to the question. Anyway, your answer made me think more thoroughly about it and made me realize some more details, so I upvoted it. Thanks!

Comment: That's not a callback, it's an object hierarchy. Nor would I call 20 lines of code overkill. And there is no reason for custom events, since everything can be handled through the interface (the form). But we can agree to disagree; glad you worked it out.