# Linking Object to UI

Tags: vba, userform

What is the best method to use to link a class to a user form?

Sorry to be hypothetical, but using actual code will lead to a question that is pages long.

Let's say I have a class that holds data about a person.

```
<<class Person>>
Public FirstName as String
Public LastName as String
Public PhoneNumber as String
<<end class>>
```

I put that data into a VBA UserForm listview.

Now, let's say I want to change the phone number to 555-555-1234 if the user clicks on that record in the listview.

I can read the interaction with the listview with the item click event.

```
Private Sub lvExample_ItemClick(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)
  ' Change the phone number
End Sub
```

What is the best way to get from Item in the above code to my actual object?  Should I add an GUID to each object and put that in the tag of the listitem, then look it up?  Should I add the listitem from the listview into the class so I can loop through all my people and then see if the Item from _ItemClick equals the Item from the object?

Comment: Adding a GUID is a good way to go, or any other ID to uniquely identify an individual person object, In your example the phone number could be unique to each person and able to act as an ID. That won't work if you expect to ever have more than 1 phone number to a person, or more than one person to a phone number.

Comment: Is your data stored in an Excel worksheet, Access database, or just a list in Word?  Where is the Person information coming from?

Comment: The data in this case is loaded from SQL.

Comment: I'm really looking for a general way to identify / link a UI element to an object.

Comment: wouldn't [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5432711/2143262) be helpful?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use either the Index property, if you don't have any unique identifier, or the Key property if you do, of the ListItem.

If you choose to use the Index property, then you can't (or at least it will greatly complicate it) add any functionality to rearrange the order of list items.

You would have populated the ListView based on the objects in a collection/recordset via the ListView.ListItems.Add method. You can use the Index property to get back to that original object based on the order of items in ListItems corresponding to the order of items in your original collection of objects.

Alternatively, if you prefer the greater flexibility of using a unique key but don't wish to modify the underlying object, then you can trivially construct a unique key (the simplest being CStr(some incrementing number)) as you add each object to ListItems, storing the keys alongside the objects.

You can then use the .Key property of the ListItem. The benefit here is the user can be allowed to modify what items are in, delete stuff etc without you having to invalidate your control and re-add all objects in order to keep the linkage between Index in source and index in the list.

E.g.:

```
Private persons As Collection
Private Sub lvExample_ItemClick(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)
    ' Change the phone number:

    'Method 1, using the index of listitem within listitems
    'to tie back to index in persons collection
    'Don't allow rearranging/sorting of items with this method for simplicity
    With persons.Item(Item.Index)
        .PhoneNumber = "555-555-1234"
        '...some stuff
    End With

    'Method 2, using a unique key
    'that you generate, as the underlying person object doesn't have a necessarily unique one
    'Items would have been added in a method similar to AddItemsExample1() below
    With persons.Item(Item.Key)
        .PhoneNumber = "555-555-1234"
        '...some stuff
    End With


End Sub

Sub AddItemsExample1()
    'Storage requirements vs. your existing recordset or whatever
    'are minimal as all it is storing is the reference to the underlying
    'person object

    'Adapt per how you have your existing objects
    'But basically get them into a keyed collection/dictionary

    Dim i As Long        
    Set persons = New Collection
    For Each p In MyPersonsSource
        persons.Add p, CStr(i)
        i = i + 1
    Next p

    'By keying them up, you can allow sorting / rearranging
    'of the list items as you won't be working off of Index position

End Sub
```

Finally, another way if you have them in a recordset returned by a DB is to add a new field (I imagine you have an existing object field) and do run an UPDATE query on your records populating it with an incrementing number (this should only effect the local recordset (check the recordset settings first of course!)). Use this as the key.

You mention in a comment to your question that you get the data from SQL. For all normal purposes with a list box it is still probably easiest to just run them through a Collection object as detailed above, but if you have e.g. 4 fields from SQL for a record in a recordset then you don't hav an 'object' in the sense of being able to call properties on it. Please specify in your question or in a comment to this if you do so, as there may be a better treatment to answer your question or the actual update operation will likely require different syntax or semantics (particularly if you need to propagate any update back to the source) :)

Comment: @mehow, I agree the question is broad, but that is purposeful, I'm asking if there is a best way to do something.  I'd appreciate any constructive criticism as to how to improve the question.

Comment: @Ifrandom importantly, how do you have 'persons'? I am assuming you have proper 'objects' as you mention a class person, so that is helpful, and I suppose updating the DB is outside the scope of the question. Anyway, did any of my suggestions help? If not, please say why not for my reference. Thanks

Comment: @lfrandom well, any answer will be primarily opinion-based. There is no `best way` as it always depends on your code-design, your implementation and your VBA skills, etc. Your question is far too broad and hardly answerable as any answerer has to consider pros and cons of his solution. One will agree other will disagree so there is no perfect solution to your problem. You also are a bit unclear in your question so trying to understand what youre trying to achieve is critical

Answer (score 0):

I would use a event driven approach.

`Person` will have properties instead of variables and assigning those properties will raise a event.

User form will have `WithEvents Person`, so that changes in related person will trigger user form code.

Person class:

```
Public Event Changed()
Private pFirstName As String
Private pLastName As String
Private pPhoneNumber As String

Public Property Get FirstName() As String
    FirstName = pFirstName
End Property

Public Property Let FirstName(ByVal v As String)
    pFirstName = v
    RaiseEvent Changed
End Property

Public Property Get LastName() As String
    LastName = pLastName
End Property

Public Property Let LastName(ByVal v As String)
    pLastName = v
    RaiseEvent Changed
End Property

Public Property Get PhoneNumber() As String
    PhoneNumber = pPhoneNumber
End Property

Public Property Let PhoneNumber(ByVal v As String)
    pPhoneNumber = v
    RaiseEvent Changed
End Property
```

Event catching in user form:

```
Public WithEvents ThisPerson As Person

Private Sub ThisPerson_Changed()
    'Update user form
End Sub
```

So whenever you assign `YourForm.RelatedObject = SomePerson`, any changes done to `SomePerson` will trigger code in `YourForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't change returned `ListItem`, I have another solution:

Add a related `ListItem` to your `Person` class:

```
Public FirstName as String
Public LastName as String
Public PhoneNumber as String
Public RelatedObject As Object
```

When populating `TreeView`, assign it:

```
Set SomeListItem = SomeTreeView.ListItems.Add(...)
Set SomePerson.RelatedObject = SomeListItems
```

So whenever you have a change in a `ListItem`:

```
Private Sub SomeListView_ItemClick(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)
    Dim p As Person
    For Each p In (...)
        If p.RelatedObject Is Item Then
            'Found, p is your person!
            p.PhoneNumber = ...
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to change your `Person` class, you can encapsulate it in another class, eg, PersonToObject:

```
Public Person As Person
Public RelatedObject As Object
```

And use `PersonToObject` as link objects.